# A problem with conditional statement shorthand

Tags: javascript, if-statement, passwords, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have this Conditional Statement that I am trying to use shorthand.

As you can see when I get on the else I don't know how to make the `passwordMatchError.setAttribute("id", "error")` to show together with the `passwordMatchError.textContent = ("Password does not match. Please retype.");`

I tried using the signs +, || and && but didnt work.

Can you guys help me out?

Many thanks.

```js
const checkThePassword = (registration) => {
    let getTheOriginalPassword = registration.password.value; //assign passwords by value, avoid const here in case of unprotected memory
    let getTheRetypedPassword = registration.retypedpassword.value;
    // Simple equality check for retyped password
    getTheOriginalPassword === getTheRetypedPassword ? passwordMatchError.setAttribute("id", "error") :  passwordMatchError.textContent = ("Password does not match. Please retype.");
    // false return is done together with error handling

}
```

Here is the original code

```js
const checkThePassword = (registration) => {
 let getTheOriginalPassword = registration.password.value; //assign passwords by value, avoid const here in case of unprotected memory
 let getTheRetypedPassword = registration.retypedpassword.value;
 // Simple equality check for retyped password
 if (getTheOriginalPassword === getTheRetypedPassword) {
  return true;
 } else {
  passwordMatchError.setAttribute("id", "error");
  passwordMatchError.textContent = ("Password does not match. Please retype.");
  return false; // false return is done together with error handling
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the return parts in parentheses and return finally a boole value.

**Please use the explicit programming with an `if` statement!**

```
const checkThePassword = (registration) => {
    let getTheOriginalPassword = registration.password.value; //assign passwords by value, avoid const here in case of unprotected memory
    let getTheRetypedPassword = registration.retypedpassword.value;
    // Simple equality check for retyped password
    return getTheOriginalPassword === getTheRetypedPassword
        ? (passwordMatchError.setAttribute("id", "error"), true)
        : (passwordMatchError.textContent = ("Password does not match. Please retype."), false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I didn't know that using shorthand for if-else is a  horrible bad practice.  At least now I learned two things.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to squash it all into one line with the conditional operator, it's possible, because assignments evaluate to expressions (unfortunately), but it's pretty unreadable, I'd highly recommend against it:

```
getTheOriginalPassword === getTheRetypedPassword
  ? '' // do nothing... unused expression
  : ( // squash two "statements" which can be evaluated as expressions into a single expression:
    passwordMatchError.setAttribute("id", "error"), // use the comma operator
    passwordMatchError.textContent = ("Password does not match. Please retype.")
  )
```

It's syntactically valid and will do what you're looking for, but it's *horrible* code. Consider using your original code instead. Best to only use the conditional operator when you want to construct an *expression* conditionally - if you want to run *statements* conditionally, use `if`/`else`.

Comment: Ok. Good to know. I thought it was a good practice maintaining the code clean using shorthand that is being advised by some websites. It kind of makes us confused about whether or not were to follow if you know what I mean. In this case, I will follow your advice.